# C# - Using type as instance variable

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I am following a guide on C# programming (The C# Players Guide 2nd Edition) and am stuck on understanding classes (page 131).

The exercise states that I should construct a **Ball** class that should have a size/radius as well as a colour instance variable. Now I have previously created a Colour class (that has two constructors with one accepting four ushort and one accepting three ushort types) but it is wanting me to *use* the Colour type I just created.

I have no idea how to do this! So far I have:

```
private int size;
private int radius;
private int throwCount;
private Colour colour;

public Ball(int size, int radius, Colour colour)
{
    this.size = size;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.colour = colour;
}
```

If I create a ball I don't know how to correctly use the colour parameter.

```
Ball myBall = new Ball(1,2, ?)
```

Can you guys help me out please and just tell me if I am doing this right?

Thanks in advance from a pure newbie!

Comment: You construct `Colour` instances in the same way e.g. `new Ball(1, 2, new Colour(1,2,3,4))`.

Comment: See how you're creating a `new Ball()`? You just need to create a `new Colour()` to pass to the `Ball` constructor.

Comment: You need to create Colour class instance and pass the Ball constructor.
Can you share Color Class?

Comment: I'm more interested in why you knew you should use the new keyword to create an instance of the Ball class, whilst you weren't sure on how you would create an instance of Colour?

Comment: I just didn't occur to me. As I was learning I have become used to passing values as parameters though I didn't realise you could "construct" instances when using the method. hope that makes sense

Comment: Yes you can create an instance of an object and pass a reference (i.e. memory address) of that object as a value to another constructor when creating another object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have at least two choices :

Either they want you to instantiate the ball as you instantiate the colour :

```
Ball myBall = new Ball(1,2, new Colour(1,2,3));
```

Either they want you to instantiate it before the ball and reuse it after, this way you can use the same instance of Colour for different balls :

```
Colour myColor = new Colour(1,2,3)
Ball myBall = new Ball(1,2, myColor );
Ball myOtherBall = new Ball(4,2, myColor );
```

Answer (score 4):

First you create a new `Colour` object, which you then pass to the `Ball` constructor method:

```
var colour = new Colour( ... );  // provide suitable parameters
Ball myBall = new Ball(1, 2, colour);
```

Or you can even do it in one line of code:

```
Ball myBall = new Ball(1, 2, new Colour( ... ));  // provide suitable parameters
```

Comment: Damnit FGITW wins again xD, though I am still confused by this question, isn't the class `Color` or is it both depending on how you feel like spelling it?

Comment: Apart from _"do it like this"_ your answer contains no explanation to _what_ the OP should be doing instead. Please [edit] your answer so the OP and later visitors learn something else than copy-pasting from it.

Comment: @CodeCaster I did that but posted it moments later sadly haha

Comment: @Fabio there's no need, fastest gun has already taken effect and there is another answer which is practically identical, it would be polluting the question with more of the same

Comment: So do i have to delete my answer now ?

Comment: @yan no, it's fine to have competing answers saying exactly the same. I'd say yours is even better than this one, because yours contains an actual explanation of what your code does.

Comment: To me the code was pretty self explanatory, OP already knew how to call methods and constructors, it was just a matter of making them see something that was rather obvious. I added some explanation anyway.

Comment: The OP wrote their first lines of C# (and then ran to Stack Overflow). Disregarding whether questions like this should be answered in the first place, there is nothing "obvious" about the code because it's all new to them, hence the need for explanation, in words, of your example code. So thanks for your edit.